# How to read html string as worksheet?

Tags: javascript, excel, sheetjs

I know XLSX.read(htmlStr) reads a html string as a workbook. I was wondering if there is a way to read it as a worksheet. I have an object as follows

```
        workboook = {
            sheets:[
                {
                    html: "<table style='width:100%'>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td>
                                <td>50</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                                <td>Eve</td>
                                <td>Jackson</td>
                                <td>94</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>",
                    sheetName: "Some Name"
                },
                {
                    html: "<table style='width:100%'>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td>
                                <td>50</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                                <td>Eve</td>
                                <td>Jackson</td>
                                <td>94</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>",
                    sheetName: "Some Name"
                }
            ]
        }
```

I want to convert each html in the "sheets" array to s worksheet and add all those workseets to a workbook. Any help/suggestions would be really great.

I can still extract the Sheet object from workbook like this:

```
...
 let xlsxWorkbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
workbook.sheets.forEach((sheet) => {

            let tempWorkbook = XLSX.read(sheet.html, {type: 'string'});
            let worksheet = tempWorkbook.Sheets.Sheet1;
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(xlsxWorkbook, worksheet, sheet.sheetName);
        });
```

But this seems more like a hack. There's gotta the a better solution